# How can I change the scroll inside the accessibility activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

When I open accessibility activity using startActivity, It takes me to the accessibility activity but the scroll stays at the top, How can I change the scrolling to my app?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, once the Accessibility settings open, your App process loses control. Unless user has rooted device, you can get control of touch/scroll over other apps.

Comment: Can you [download this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truedevelopersstudio.automatictap.autoclicker) and take a look? It works well with this app how!!

Comment: I'm sure It's possible because there a lot of apps like the app above but I should find a way to do it